# Capturing variations of first and last name using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Postgresql 8.0.2 Redshift

I have a bunch of names in a database that look like this stored under the value `full_name`:

```
full_name
Jeff Davis
Michael Scott
Eric Wilson
Anna Jones-Porter
Lisa Marie Scott
A.J. Jackson
```

What I'm trying to do is create two new fields for `first_name` and `last_name`.

I initially tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
full_name,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(full_name, '^\\w+') first_name,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(full_name, ' \\w+') last_name
FROM 
schema.table
```

But that only handles the first three records because it only accounts for people who have two character strings in their `full_name` separated by one space. So it doesn't work for the bottom three records.

What would it look like if I wanted to write a query that properly captures ALL these variations of first and last names? For ones like `Lisa Marie Scott` the `first_name` would be Lisa and `last_name` would be Scott.

Expected results would look like:

```
full_name   first_name  last_name
Jeff Davis  Jeff    Davis
Michael Scott   Michael Scott
Eric Wilson Eric    Wilson
Anna Jones-Porter   Anna    Jones-Porter
Lisa Marie Scott    Lisa    Scott
A.J. Jackson    A.J.    Jackson
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the DDL and insert statements for the test data it would help who ever is answering the question
Anyways here is how you can do it.

- Use regexp_split_to_array will split the full name into an array of
  words
- Then you take the first occurrence as first name and last
  occurrence as last name.
- To find the last occurrence use the
  array_length function

x

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    full_name VARCHAR(100)
) ;

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES 
    ('Jeff Davis'),
    ('Michael Scott'),
    ('Eric Wilson'),
    ('Anna Jones-Porter'),
    ('Lisa Marie Scott'),
    ('A.J. Jackson');

-- this was from V14
select full_name, 
       name_array[1] as first_name, 
       name_array[array_length(name_array, 1)] as last_name
from (
    SELECT full_name, 
           regexp_split_to_array(full_name, '\s+') as name_array
    from TEST
) as x

-- this was from V8
select full_name, name_array[1] as first_name, name_array[(array_upper(name_array, 1))]
from (
    SELECT full_name, string_to_array(full_name, ' ') as name_array
    from test
) as x

-- redshift solution
select full_name, name_array[0]::VARCHAR as first_name, name_array[(get_array_length(name_array)-1)]::VARCHAR as last_name
from (
    SELECT full_name, split_to_array(full_name, ' ') as name_array
    from schema_poc.test
) as x 


**full_name         first_name  name_array**
Jeff Davis          Jeff        Davis
Michael Scott       Michael     Scott
Eric Wilson         Eric        Wilson
Anna Jones-Porter   Anna        Jones-Porter
Lisa Marie Scott    Lisa        Scott
A.J. Jackson        A.J.        Jackson
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I tried it and got this response back:

`Status: Failed

Error in SQL: function regexp_split_to_array(character varying, "unknown") does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`

For the record, I'm using Postgresql 8.0.2

Comment: updated above for Version 8..

Comment: Weird. I just ran it and got this message: `Error in SQL: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: I guess you need to make it clear on which database you are using.. Postgres or redshift??

Comment: My apologies. It is a Postgres Redshift.

Comment: Redshift is not postgres. Redshift is a MPP database, anyways see the solution in Redhshift above.